# How to show animation when section on view and stop repeating

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to add animation to a particular section in the middle of my webpage. I added animation successfully, however it repeats multiple times. I want to stop repeating it.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jm1axqz/)

If you scroll, the console section, you can easily understand my problem. I want to show the animation once, when the user scroll at that particular section.

```js
const about = document.querySelector("#aboutSection");

// object of animation script
const t1 = new TimelineMax();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('#aboutSection').each(function() {
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
    var imageHeight = $(this).height();
    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (imagePos < topOfWindow + imageHeight && imagePos + imageHeight > topOfWindow) {
      t1.fromTo(about, 1.2, {
        y: "100%"
      }, {
        y: "0%",
        ease: Power2.easeInOut
      });
    }
  });
  $('#aboutSection').stop(true, true);
});
```

```css
#aboutSection .jumbotron {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #004030;
  background-image: url(https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/gradient1.jpg);
  height: 550px;
}

#aboutSection .jumbotron h1 {
  margin-top: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="aboutSection" class="lazyload">
  <h1 class="sectionTitle text-center">ABOUT</h1>
  <p id="about_para">Abou something interesting random wors or details or nothing to show off and etc extra words</p>
</section>

<!-- To add animation -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Wy4KH0O+AuzjMm1w5QfZ5j5/y8Q/kcUktK9mPUVaUoBvh3QPUZB822W/vy7ULqri3yR8daH3F58+Y8Z08qzeg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TimelineMax.min.js" integrity="sha512-lJDBw/vKlGO8aIZB8/6CY4lV+EMAL3qzViHid6wXjH/uDrqUl+uvfCROHXAEL0T/bgdAQHSuE68vRlcFHUdrUw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Can you create a better demo. I am unable to see what the problem is.

Comment: @Aslam please go to the link and try to scroll the console, and you will see my about section is repeating

Answer (score 0):

If you use a variable to track if it is scrolldown or not then you can avoid the repeating problem. So you can edit the javaScript code like this....

```
scrolledDown = false;
$(window).scroll(function () {
var current = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (current >= (about.offsetWidth-100) && !scrolledDown) {
        t1.fromTo(about, 1.5, { y:"100%", opacity: 0 }, { y: "0%", opacity: 1 });
        scrolledDown = true;
    }

});
```